# How enable magento Go Api settings

Tags: php, magento

WS-I Compliance for Magento Go

Can I generate a ws-i compliant wsdl for the Magento Go solution? This seems to be available for the other Magento products (according to forum under Services > Magento Core API > WS-I Compliance to Yes). But I can't find that setting in the Magento Go admin console

Comment: Not really a programming question.  I'd contact Magento Go Support and ask if they provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on WS-I Compliance from Version 1.1.1.4.

This is the [release notes](http://go.magento.com/support/releases/index/page/2/) for version 1.1.1.0

> Version 1.1.1.0 – July 17, 2012
>
> What's New
>
> Please see blog for more details on this release along with UK
>   features. Implemented UK Knowledge Base for UK based customers.
>
> - Added additional PayPal option PayPal Advance.
> - Automatic PayPal Express accelerated on-boarding.
> - Royal Mail shipping method.
> - VAT on shipping for entire orders.
> - **API WS-I Compliance enabled for Magento Go**
>
> Minor Changes & Fixes
>
> - Twenty-five additional minor changes and fixes.